# Pacman could not find gnome-system-tools ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I tried to install gnome-system-tools on ArchLinux using pacman .

I've run pacman -Syy before but pacman could not find the package.

Here is my pacman.conf file

```
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
#GPGDir      = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
# If upgrades are available for these packages they will be asked for first
SyncFirst   = pacman
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -C - -f %u > %o
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
Architecture = auto

CheckSpace
SigLevel = Never

# REPOSITORIES

[testing]
#SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist


[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[core]
#SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
#SigLevel = PackageOptional
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

#[community-testing]
#SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
#SigLevel = PackageOptional
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[multilib-testing]
#SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[multilib]
#SigLevel = PackageOptional
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

Do I miss a repository ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should check out the newer [`gnome-control-center`](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=gnome-control&maintainer=&last_update=&flagged=&limit=50) package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This package [doesn't exist, according to the Packages database](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=gnome-system-tools&maintainer=&last_update=&flagged=&limit=50).

Comment: It's weired. Seems like the package have been removed.. Do you know if gnome-system-tools are deprecated ?

Comment: I think it has gone deprecated with GNOME 3, judging from [the files on their FTP server](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-system-tools/).

Answer (score -1):

Try installing gnome-system-tools from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=62356) by

`yaourt -S gnome-system-tools`

Comment: Why has the poster's choice of AUR helper been replaced here? It adds nothing to the answer and, arguably, changes the context. If they specify `packer`, then it should either be left that way or genericized completely.

Comment: @jasonwryan it looks like there were two edits and not a simply replacement of packer with yaourt. The first edit embedded the link and removed the detailed packer instructions. The second edit added detailed yaourt instructions.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Yes, I read the history. My question was to warlock to prompt some reflection on why {s}he is promoting one AUR helper over another (particularly when the OP's choice is the better one).